# Ember local live list

Tags: list, ember.js, each

I try to do simple application using Ember. Index controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  schools: [{name:"Old school"}],
  actions:{
    add: function(){
        var schools = this.get("schools");
        schools.push({name: 'New school'});
        this.set("schools",schools);
    }
  }
});
```

Index template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <button type="button" {{action "add"}}>Add school</button>
    <ul>
      {{#each school in schools}}
         <li>{{school.name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

When i lunch application on start i see:

- Old school

and when I hit *add button* nothing happens, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `pushObject` in order for ember to know that a value has been added to the list.  And there is no need to set it afterward.

```
add: function(){
    var schools = this.get("schools");
    schools.pushObject({name: 'New school'});
}
```